# color detection from green to red in opencv python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, colors

I am learning opencv in python and I have coded a program to detect green and red objects through the webcam. Now I would like my program to execute a function as soon as a red colour is detected. The function takes a screenshot of the moment the red object is detected, this is simple, I know how to do this part but I am stuck trying to figure out how to execute my function after a red object is detected.

Some real life example of this would be a traffic light. As soon as the colour changes from red to green, a function would be called to let off the brakes. I simply do not know how to connect the colour change to a function.

Below is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# the screenshot function will be here
# def screenshot():

while(1):
   _, imageFrame = webcam.read()
   

   hsvFrame = cv2.cvtColor(imageFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

   red_lower = np.array([136, 87, 111], np.uint8)
   red_upper = np.array([180, 255, 255], np.uint8)
   red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsvFrame, red_lower, red_upper)

   green_lower = np.array([25, 52, 72], np.uint8)
   green_upper = np.array([102, 255, 255], np.uint8)
   green_mask = cv2.inRange(hsvFrame, green_lower, green_upper)

   kernal = np.ones((5,5), "uint8")

   red_mask = cv2.dilate(red_mask, kernal)
   res_red = cv2.bitwise_and(imageFrame, imageFrame, 
                              mask = red_mask)

   
   green_mask = cv2.dilate(green_mask, kernal)
   res_green = cv2.bitwise_and(imageFrame, imageFrame, mask = green_mask)

   contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(red_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


   for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if(area > 300):
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            imageFrame = cv2.rectangle(imageFrame, (x, y), 
                                       (x + w, y + h), 
                                       (0, 0, 255), 2)
              
            cv2.putText(imageFrame, "red", (x, y),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0,
                        (0, 0, 255))

            
   
   cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(green_mask,
                                           cv2.RETR_TREE,
                                           cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
      
   for pic, contour in enumerate(cnts):
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if(area > 300):
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            imageFrame = cv2.rectangle(imageFrame, (x, y), 
                                       (x + w, y + h),
                                       (0, 255, 0), 2)
              
            cv2.putText(imageFrame, "Green", (x, y),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 
                        1.0, (0, 255, 0))

   cv2.imshow("colors", imageFrame)

   if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      cap.release()
      cv2.destroyAllWindows()
      break
```

Comment: Is the red or green always in the same location in your images over time?

Comment: no it can be on different parts of the screen

Comment: @mashwaniT Place your function within the `if` condition where you have filtered contours greater than area threshold.

Comment: @JeruLuke That works when the first red object is detected, but what if a second red object is detected?

Comment: @mashwaniT I don't understand. How many objects are you detecting? I thought the code was detecting a change to red color and that's why I commented. If my assumption is wrong please elaborate on your problem statement.